# mobile developing using html5

Tags: html, mobile-website

can anybody suggest a framework for developing mobile applications using html5 ? I want the moblie web applications to look and feel native on Android, Apple, and BlackBerry devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) as it allows you to create native apps using HTML.

There are various libraries and frameworks which can help with styling the UI to look like native apps.

Note however that such support for older BlackBerry devices (

Answer (score 1):

http://www.appcelerator.com/

If you're looking to make it feel and look native, but run in browser, try JqueryMobile